# performance problem - growing memory and cpu usage

Tags: performance, memory, memory-leaks, cpu

I have windows application I wrote.
I installed it on virtual server (vmware) that holds windows server 2008 and for some reason the application getting bigger and bigger. I used perfmon in order to see maybe there is a memory leak - but as I understand, there isn't:
[image: perfmon]

Here is the proccess in task manager:
[image: task manager]

There are also two proccesses that use a lot of memory and cpu but are steady and not growing like SimeserManager.exe.

The memory growing slows the surfing on sited that this server holds.
Before this week I used the my application on phizical server with windows server 2003 and there were no problem with surfing. I can't restore the situtaion in the phizical machine since I don't have it anymore, but I don't believe there was memory error when using the phizical server.

The application is written in c# .net using visual studio 2010.

What can be the problem?
Where can I get some clues?

**UPDATE**
I get ANTS memory profiler and tried to seek for the problem. I created memory snapshots and here is the results:
[image: ANTS memory profiler]

Now I'm really lost.
I tryed the standart filters but didn't manage to find a clue for the problem. In the image you can see there is increase in the private bytes. Does that sais there is a memory leak?

Can anyone give me some clues how to continue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't have enough information here to really debug your application. However, there are tools you can use to identify and solve this issue in your application. I would suggest you use the ANTS Memory Profiler from RedGate to help you look for your problem.  Here is a link to it:

http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/

It isn't free but it is cheap and extremely effective.  Get the 14-day free trial and run it on your application.  I would go as far as to say that if it doesn't find the issue, the issue probably isn't with your application.

As for the other processes that are taking a lot of memory, this is normal.  SQL Server tries to get as much memory as possible.  Running other applications on the same box as a SQL server may cause you performance issues if you aren't careful.  Here is a good article on how SQL Server uses memory:

http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jonathan_kehayias/archive/2009/08/24/troubleshooting-the-sql-server-memory-leak-or-understanding-sql-server-memory-usage.aspx

As for IIS memory usage (the other process that was using lots of memory), there could be multiple reasons for this.  I would suggest you read through this forum to get a better idea of what it could be (if it truly is an issue):

http://forums.iis.net/t/1150494.aspx

Comment: @Naor - it looks like the "issue" here is with the Entity Framework.  It may be that you are just storing a lot of records in your application or it may mean that you aren't releasing the records after you are done with them.  It also looks like you are doing some Entity relationships inside your code.  This might cause some memory issues as well.  I would suggest that if you are struggling with how to use the profiler that you look at some of the tutorials.  You will need to dig into the profiler and your application to find the possible issue.

Comment: You right. I didn't disposed the contexts. After disposing it - everything went to normal. Thanks!